# Rails 3 with Grape issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, routes, grape-api

I've been following this post

http://martinciu.com/2011/01/mounting-grape-api-inside-rails-application.html

I put the module into the lib directory and added the line to *routes.rb* like shown

When I do

```
rails s
```

I get an error, saying

```
uninitialized constant MyApp (NameError)
```

What's missing? Do I need to put the module some place else? Or let rails know somehow where it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of that blogpost clarifies that problem in the comments:

> You can add 'require "lib/api" to your config/routes.rb file or you
>   can require automatically all files from lib directory by adding this
>   line to your config/application.rb;
>
> config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

Answer (score 0):

Well ok, it's easy. I forgot to require 'myApp' in routes.rb....